# Gnome Alacarte Menu Editor - Annoying reload when editing an entry

Tags: linux, gnome

Does anyone know of a better way to edit the applications menu in Gnome?

Each time I make a change in an item, the whole menu reloads, and I have to constantly "re-expand" the entries to find the next one I want to edit.

This is really annoying.

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 x64 (alacarte 0.11.10-0ubuntu1). I've now realized that this behavior is very erratic, as sometimes it occurs (most of the time), sometimes it doesn't.

Any operation will trigger this behavior, like deleting an item, or moving it to another menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit, specifing what distro you are using, what version of *alacarte* and what steps are necessary to reproduce the behaviour? I am under Karmic 64 bit and could not find any behavior I could match with your description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erratic behaviours are difficult to debug. I used Jaunty until last month and did not experience that. If I were in your situation I would probably try to see if newer versions of alacarte have been [backported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports), and if yes, I would try to install them. Compiling the latest source code is also an option, if you really can't stand this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I was wondering whether this was a somewhat common behavior (as I seldom use alacarte, I didn't bother to check until now).

Anyway, you suggestions are good. I checked for the latest version, but there's no backport. It doesn't seem to have many changes do, but I'll try to compile anyway and see if that makes a difference.

Thanks.